# $\lambda_{\max}(XDX^T)$ smaller than $\lambda_{\max}(XX^T)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-linear-algebra

$X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ and $D$ is a $d$-dimensional diagonal matrix. All elements on the diagonal of $D$ are in $[0,1]$. I am wondering whether the largest eigenvalue $\lambda_{\max}(XDX^T)$ of $XDX^T$ is smaller or equal to $\lambda_{\max}(XX^T)$. Intuitively, this is true and when $D=I_n$, we will have $\lambda_{\max}(XDX^T) = \lambda_{\max}(XX^T)$. But I cannot prove it or  disapprove it. Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is indeed true that $\lambda_{\max}(XDX^T) \leq \lambda_{\max}(XX^T)$. In particular, we note that for any positive semidefinite definite matrices $A,B$, we have $\lambda_{\max}(A + B) \geq \lambda_{\max}(A)$. Thus, we have
$$
\lambda_{\max}(X^TX) = \lambda_{\max}(X^TDX + X^T(I - D)X) \geq \lambda_{\max}(X^TDX).
$$